# ODATA 4 How to get current user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, odata

```
public IHttpActionResult Current() {
    var user = UserManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.GetUserName()).Result;
    return Ok(user);
}
```

I has an error: No non-OData HTTP route registered.

Methods GET, Post, Put works fine.

Comment: Is this method in an Odata controller? How do you send request to this method? You might need to define it as a function in the odata model builder.

Comment: Yes. Request like http://localhost:1288/users/current

Comment: Do you register this function in your model builder?